# Photography of Space ships

Tags: equipment-recommendation

How do I photograph Extraterrestrial vehicles in the sky? Do I need infrared or some other type of lens? Is there a certain spectrum or wavelength that I need to use?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "Extraterrestrial", do you mean "not of Earth origin", or are you referring to human-made vehicles in flight?

Comment: Yes,correct. I would like to photograph “cloned” vehicles. I truly believe they exist, en mass, and I believe I saw footage of vehicles flying in/ around our atmosphere from nasa. I want to “see” what the human eye cannot. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to answer from a photography point of view without knowing the physical / optical properties of the theoretical alien spacecraft.

Comment: No offense meant, but I think this might be a perfect fit for the "worldbuilding" site.

Comment: Also, mind that the raleigh criterion is pretty much mandatory - someone installing a small enough craft high enough to be outside the theoretical limits of any practically buildable equipment will have won, period. If you would need a telescope of an impossible to build focal length to reach a narrow enough viewing angle at practical apertures to get the needed angular resolution - game over.

Comment: I believe that there must be ways to photograph items that can not be seen with the human eye alone. Infrared is one way. Heat can create an image. I’m interested in knowing what other photographers have used to capture images unable to be seen with the unaided human eye. Slow motion/freeze frame bullet meets an apple is a good example, for instance. Surly there are ways to photograph images outside of the, very small, range of what humans can see of the visual spectrum. My quest is fixing individuals who achieved this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - but first you need to know where it is... or even ***if*** it is... & also what frequencies it might show up at. You perhaps need to then weigh this speculation against the colossal resources of NASA & observatories who do this kind of thing for a living, & wonder, if they're so common, why haven't they managed to photograph them yet & why you are likely to succeed where they have failed.

Comment: @Tetsujin people who want to photograph alien spacecraft don't believe that NASA _can't_; they believe that NASA can, but prefer to hide this from us. Hence, make your own photo. Good luck.

Comment: @osullic - but... but... that would imply there is some kind of [don't say it too loud...] conspiracy!!! Imagine... invisible aliens that everybody in authority is aware of but they just won't tell us about it... maybe they hide just under the edge, out past the south pole... ;))

Comment: The camera is not important, but you need to wear a tinfoil hat to get any images.  Sorry, i had to.   I do not discount the existence of life elsewhere in the universe ( or all around us but unseen ) but i suspect that they are not traveling in "spaceships" . ( does "life" mean biological entity? Are biological entities bound by physics ? ) Earth cameras are a product of our physical environment and as such are limited to the  world in which they were developed. At least that is what we think,  We do know cameras can see light form parts of the spectrum that we humans seem to not be able to.

Comment: As long as these covert spacecraft do not crash through my roof ... I would consider them someone elses business anyway :) Otherwise, the question would be if any experimental lens can be salvaged and adapted from the wreck...

Comment: Hi Billy! All space shenanigans aside: would you be able to reword the question to focus more on photographic techniques to capture things that cannot be seen by the naked eye? Then, once you have answers for that, you can use your expertise to determine if/which technique is suitable to find extraterrestrials.

Comment: Wasn't "very technical photography", like radiotelescopes, thermal imaging, machine vision, once determined off topic?

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need any special filters to photograph spacecraft or general off planet stuff. [Nasa offers a nice tutorial on photographing the space station you can find here](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/photographing_iss.html) their recommended equipment list is:

> - Digital Single-Lens Reflex (DSLR) camera
> - 600 mm lens (or the largest you have)
> - 2X telephoto lens converter (amplifies lens)
> - Trigger cable (minimizes camera shake)
> - Tripod (heavy duty works best)
> - Sandbag (keeps tripod stable)

The best chunk of the instructions is as follows:

> Harnett set her camera’s shutter speed to 1/1600 of a second, aperture
>   at f/8 and ISO to 2500. You may need to adjust your settings to let in
>   more or less light depending on the size and brightness of the moon or
>   your foreground object, but this is a good starting-point.
>
> Use the High Continuous Burst setting to capture the most images per
>   second. Setting the camera to save the photos in raw image format is
>   best. Be sure to use the manual focus.
>
> It is a good idea to take a few test shots to ensure everything is set
>   as you want. A few minutes before the station is expected to fly over,
>   check the viewfinder again to ensure the moon is still in the shot, as
>   it also is moving across the sky.
>
> The station will be easy to identify when it comes into view as it is
>   extremely bright and moves rather quickly. You can see it with the
>   naked eye.
>
> Once the space station is in the field of view (or close to it), press
>   and hold down the cabled trigger release until the station leaves your
>   field of view. Then check the photos on your camera to see if they
>   turned out the way you wanted.

Generally the biggest issue photographing things off the surface of the planet is the speed at which they move relative to the plane you are on. You can correct some of this with a [star tracker](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1092107-REG/sky_watcher_s20520_star_adventurer_motorized_mount.html?ap=y&gclid=CjwKCAiAt4rfBRBKEiwAC678Kfdml1TIuqx35WvoY28MLcHBCeMTZh2_nRqBE_WZQPU8nH_sTln08hoC_vAQAvD_BwE&smp=y) but not everything.

You will also, eventually run into a resolution issue (at sufficient distance). At sufficiently large distances the object you may be trying to photograph is smaller than a single pixel or film grain so you cant actually resolve it or your lens cant actually resolve it into a single point, [this is known as angular resolution](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~thuard/astr288c/lecture6-notes.pdf). When photographing off or onto the surface of the planet you also need to contend with the atmosphere which acts as a semi-unpredictable and often frustrating filter. This was a big issue [encountered by early high altitude reconnoissance satellites.](http://omegataupodcast.net/258-the-history-and-technology-of-spy-satellites/)

There are [filters you can get that help eliminate localized light sources](http://alexconu.com/nisi-natural-night/) that are interfering with your image. Some of these things can also be corrected in post.

---

Edit: r.e. the comments.

The above notes on tracking distant high speed objects are still relevant but for photographing things out of the visible light spectrum you will need to turn to other methods. Ultimately the display needs to render in a human readable manner of which there are lots of options and it depends on the spectrum you are looking for. At some point you are talking about the visualization of EM radiation

Above the human visible spectrum you have ionizing radiation which you can see with a [cloud chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber)

Below the visible spectrum there are [several Infrared sensitive film stocks](https://www.lomography.com/magazine/320088-6-infrared-films-for-that-otherworldly-glow) out there for capturing whats just outside the visible spectrum.

MIT has developed a camera of sorts that [operates in the microwave spectrum](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/semiconductors/optoelectronics/mits-3d-microwave-camera-can-see-through-walls). Provided the subject is at least somewhat radio reflexive you should be able to use the device to "see it"

> One other trick that the microwave camera is capable of is
>   multispectral imaging. As the camera takes each measurement, the
>   microwave emitter sweeps through a frequency range of 7.835 GHz to
>   12.817 GHz over 10 ms (your microwave oven operates at 2.45 GHz). Different materials respond to the microwaves differently at lower and
>   higher frequencies, and the camera can separate out these spectra.
>   This gives you an image with multiple frequency response “colors,” and
>   the patterns of colors that you get provides information about the
>   materials.

Ultimately you would really need the receiver portion of this device, assuming what ever you are trying to photograph emits some kind of EM radiation you don't need to actually ping it you merely need to receive and display it.

Below that you are talking about radio waves, you should [check out this answer over on ee.se](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84052/is-there-a-rf-viewer-like-a-thermo-camera) for more info on visualizing radio waves

Comment: While all very good and helpful, unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. The question is asking about how to photograph hypothesized subjects that don't reflect light in the human visible light spectrum (about 390–700 nm).

Comment: @scottbb those notes were in the comments were not there when I posted this, ill update with some more info.

Comment: I believe that there must be ways to photograph items that can not be seen with the human eye alone. Infrared is one way. Heat can create an image. I’m interested in knowing what other photographers have used to capture images unable to be seen with the unaided human eye. Slow motion/freeze frame bullet meets an apple is a good example, for instance. Surly there are ways to photograph images outside of the, very small, range of what humans can see of the visual spectrum. My quest is finding the individuals who achieved this. Thanks.

Comment: @BillySzigety I think you have two different questions in there. [High speed photography is](https://www.youtube.com/user/theslowmoguys) is much different than photography concerned with EM radiation outside of the human eyes ability to see. There is a lot of equipment available for high speed photography even at the hobby level but all these things still occur in the _visible spectrum_ . EM radiation imaging is much more complex and there is less out there for it at the hobby level.

Comment: Dave, high speed was used as an example, we all should have an idea of what it takes to conceive that. Thanks